# Check if notification is clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.android

I have application with an alarm, every time that the alarm fires, the app sends the user a notification, is possible to know if the user clicked or close the notification?

The code for my notification is below:

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
       Settings.AlarmNotification = 1;

            if (System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
            {
                Settings.AlarmCount =0;
            }

            var title = "Test";
            var message = "Something";

            Intent backIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            backIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);



            var resultIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));



            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.GetActivities(context, 0,
                new Intent[] { backIntent, resultIntent },
                PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var builder =
                new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .SetContentTitle(title)
                    .SetContentText(message)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                    .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All);

            builder.SetContentIntent(pending);
            var notification = builder.Build();
            var manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
            manager.Notify(1331, notification);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Notification.Builder` and `NotificationCompat.Builder` both have a `SetDeleteIntent` method you could use to trigger a `BroadcastReceiver` when the notification is closed (even with "CLEAR ALL"). This `BroadcastReceiver` would also trigger when the notification is clicked on since you have the notification set to auto cancel.

First, setup a `PendingIntent` to send to the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
var deleteIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(NotificationBroadcastReceiver));
deleteIntent.SetAction("Action");
deleteIntent.PutExtra("key", key);
// TODO: Set extras as needed.
var deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, _notificationId, deleteIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
```

Then associate the `PendingIntent` with the notification:

```
var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, RouteUpdateChannelId)
            .SetDefaults(NotificationCompat.DefaultAll)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            // TODO: Setup Notification
            .SetDeleteIntent(deletePendingIntent);
```

Now you can add the `BroadcastReceiver` to your Android project:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class NotificationBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action == "Action")
        {
            // TODO: Grab extras from the Intent as needed.
            var key = intent.GetStringExtra("key");
            // TODO: Handle notification closing here...
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "trigger" your `MainActivity` when the user clicks on your notification, you can set the notification's `PendingIntent` with an `Intent` that includes any additional information you want to pass to it.

```
var title = "Winner, Winner, Chicken Dinner";
var message = "You just won a million StackOverflow reputation points";

var alarmIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
alarmIntent.SetAction("ASushiNotification");
alarmIntent.PutExtra("MessageFromSushiHangover", message);
var pending = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

// set your notification as normal using ".SetContentIntent(pending)"
```

On the `MainActivty`, set its `LaunchMode` to `SingleTop` so the OS will reuse the activity if it is all already running vs. starting a new one:

```
[Activity(Label = "A Super Duper App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon", LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
```

There are two entry points into `MainActvity` for the notification intent, if the activity is already running, `OnNewIntent` will be called with the intent that you setup on the notification. If your app is **not running**, `MainActvity` will be create as normal *but* will include the intent from from the notification.

Create a method (`NotificationClickedOn`) that does something with the intent and any extra data you applied to it:

```
void NotificationClickedOn(Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.Action == "ASushiNotification" && intent.HasExtra("MessageFromSushiHangover"))
    {
        /// Do something now that you know the user clicked on the notifcation...
        var notificationMessage = intent.Extras.GetString("MessageFromSushiHangover");
        var winnerToast = Toast.MakeText(this, $"{notificationMessage}.\n\n Please send 2 BitCoins to SushiHangover to process your winning ticket! ", ToastLength.Long);
        winnerToast.SetGravity(Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center, 0, 0);
        winnerToast.Show();
    }
}
```

In your `MainActivty`, override the `OnNewIntent` method and call `NotificationClickedOn`:

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    NotificationClickedOn(intent);
}
```

In your existing `OnCreate` override add a call `NotificationClickedOn`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    ~~~~~

    NotificationClickedOn(Intent);

    ~~~~~
 }
```

Now when someone clicks on your notification you will be able to determine that whether your app was already running or not:

[image]

Your application & activity will be created if needed and the `MainActivity` will be shown and the toast will appear:

[image]

Comment: I just want to put in a settings variable if the user clicked the notification or not, i will have a if in the MainActivity, if settings variable is true then can do this.

Comment: @Phill You can update that setting variable in the example `NotificationClickedOn` method, just set some ID value in `alarmIntent.SetAction` like "UpdateSettings" and test to see if the intent that got passed in includes that action and if so update your variable...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the @Trevor Balcom answer is simpler and does what i want.